# how to access Canvas mouse point on action of button from another window Pyqt5

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt5

I am PyQt5 and PyQgis novice. Below code snippet is my main window application. Below code throw a main Window with QGsMapCanvas as central widget as canvas, which displays maps.

On menu action and i can display Pyqt5 window , there are 4 such GUI. all are runnning successfully. But..  Mainwindow (canvas) and GUI (from menu bar action) are two different window.

I want to access polyline or point or polygon drawn in canvas on Action of QPushButton in GUI.

that is how to access mouse points or QgsPointXY of Canvas to be shared with other Pyqt5 GUI (on action of button).

Note: i am able to draw line in canvas using custom LineTool (QgsMapToolEmitpoint) from toolbar action in mainwindow, but can not shared with other GUI on button event.

```
import sys,os
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import *




# Environment variable QGISHOME must be set to the install directory
# before running the application
qgis_prefix = os.getenv("QGISHOME")

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('MainMenu.ui', self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Standalone Desktop Application")
        self.show() 


    self._mks=None
    self._mkb=None
    self._mkw=None
    self._mka=None

    # Find & connect Menu1
    self.item1 = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QAction, 'menuItem1')
    self.item1.triggered.connect(self.showGUI1) # Remember to pass the definition/method, not the return value!

    # Find & connect  Menu2
    self.item2 = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QAction, 'menuItem2')
    self.item2.triggered.connect(self.showGUI2) # Remember to pass the definition/method, not the return value!

    # Find & connect Menu3
    self.item3 = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QAction, 'menuItem3')
    self.item3.triggered.connect(self.showGUI3) # Remember to pass the definition/method, not the return value!



    # Find & connect Menu4
    self.item4 = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QAction, 'menuItem4')
    self.item4.triggered.connect(self.showGUI4) # Remember to pass the definition/method, not the return value!      


    # Find canvas object
    self.canvas = self.findChild(QgsMapCanvas, 'canvas')
    self.canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True) 

    # Load A Test Vector layer and display in canvas
    self.loadGISLayer()

def showGUI1(self):
    # This is executed when the menu item is pressed
    print(' GUI 1 To be Launched')
    self._mks=showUI1()
    self._mks.show()

def showGUI2(self):
    # This is executed when the menu item is pressed
    print(' GUI 2 To be Launched')
    self._mkb=showUI2()
    self._mkb.show()

def showGUI3(self):
    # This is executed when the menu item is pressed
    print(' GUI 3 To be Launched')
    self._mkw=showUI3()
    self._mkw.show()

def showGUI4(self):
    # This is executed when the menu item is pressed
    print('  GUI 4 To be Launched')
    self._mka=showUI4()
    self._mka.show()



# Class for UI1
class showUI1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(showUI1, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('UI1.ui', self)


# Class for UI2
class showUI2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(showUI2, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('UI2.ui', self)

# Class for UI3
class showUI3(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(showUI3, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('UI3.ui', self)           


# Class for UI4
class showUI4(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(showUI4, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('UI4.ui', self)           



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

print(qgis_prefix)
print("------------------------------------------------")
print(QgsApplication.showSettings())

window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```